# react router 2.0 Browser back button routing

Tags: react-router, reactjs-flux

I have one page let it's 'B',coming from page 'A'. In page 'B', I have drop down selection, which calls and change the state. Now when I am going back, it's not going to page 'A'. Second back, it's going(It's depend upon how many times you change the drop down selection).

Any idea, How to handle this?

I am using flux and react-router for this application

Answer (score 0):

Can you please paste your component code or create a Fiddle of it.
I feel you are doing navigation to same page on onChange of the dropdown(may be mistakenly) or may be you are doing a form post.

Also please mention whether you are using browser-history or hash-history

Answer (score 0):

Using **browser-history**.

On page A

```
<Link to={{ pathname: urlBase+'productDetails', query: { qid: 123 } }}> </Link>
```

On page B, right now doing increment and decrement insted of dropdown.

```
_incrementQuantity: function(e)
{
    var quantity = this.state.productQuantity;
    if(quantity == NaN){
        quantity = 0 ;
    }
    var updatedQuantity = quantity + 1;
    this.setState({ productQuantity : updatedQuantity, buttonText : "Add to Cart" });
},

/* Decrementing the Product Quantity*/
_decrementQuantity : function(e){

    var quantity = this.state.productQuantity;
    var updatedQuantity = quantity-1;
    if(updatedQuantity<=0){
        updatedQuantity = 1;
    }
    this.setState({ productQuantity : updatedQuantity, buttonText : "Add to Cart" });
},
```

**On Render**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick={this._decrementQuantity} ></a>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick={this._incrementQuantity} > </a>
```

it solved the problem instead of javascript:void(0), I have written # .

If any suggestion on these code, please let me know. Thank you